# Dialogflow Messenger - Embed on Website Fails via 403 and CORS Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

As the title suggests, I am following the steps from Dialogflow's documentation to use the Messenger widget on a website.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger

The docs suggest that we can copy the script to embed on our site.  I tested this on a simple HTML page locally, and while I see the widget on the page, the bot is not responding.  When inspecting via developer tools, I am seeing a 403 and a CORS error.

[image]

The documentation suggests that it should be as simple as pasting the snippet inside the body of the page, so I am rather stumped as to what else I would need to do enable a public version of my agent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user has possibly no permission to access the API, I would suggest going to your project's IAM page and review the role of the user. You can see more details here in the link: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/access-control also more stacktrace of the error might be helpful to investigate the issue.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using, details on how you are authorizing requests, etc. HTTP Status 403 means **Forbidden** which typically means an authorization problem.

Comment: I suspect that this was an issue because I was simply just popping the widget on a static HTML page on my local machine.  When I tested this against a simple page running on a VM, the widget behaved as expected.  Basically, I wasn't running a proper webserver.